# Tool for sending messages to ActiveMQ manually

Tags: activemq-classic

I have worked on IBM MQ and this is the first project where I am to work on ActiveMQ. After reading basic tutorial I found that both are similar. So I started creating small applications to listen to some queues.

Working with IBM MQ, I used to use RFHUtil tool to browse/send messages to queue which provided features to set message headers as well.
In activeMQ I am sending messages from localhost admin console. I do not find options to set message header from here. For example if I want to set source system in the message header. Is there any way/tool to get this feature on activeMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like hermes jms
Be sure to pick the Head version if you want support for headers. Its pretty similar to RFHUtil but allows "all" JMS providers.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130111020038/http://hermesjms.com/patches/

I also made a command line tool for the same task which is handy, called [A](https://github.com/northlander/a).